# What are the default values for arch and code options when using nvcc?

Tags: cuda, nvcc

When compiling your CUDA code, you have to select for which architecture your code is being generated. `nvcc` provides two parameters to specify this architecture, basically:

- `arch` specifies the virtual arquictecture, which can be `compute_10`, `compute_11`, etc.
- `code` specifies the real architecture, which can be `sm_10`, `sm_11`, etc.

So a command like this:

```
nvcc x.cu -arch=compute_13 -code=sm_13
```

Will generate 'cubin' code for devices with 1.3 compute capability. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Which I would like to know is which are the default values for these two parameters? **Which is the default architecture that nvcc uses when no value for** `arch` **or** `code` **is specified?**

Comment: If you compile your code using the verbose flag you'll see the default virtual architecture used.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I've finally managed to discover the default values. My fault for not reading the whole chapter on GPU compilation in the NVCC documentation from the beginning to the very very end. So,

```
nvcc x.cu
```

is equivalent for

```
nvcc x.cu –arch=compute_10 -code=sm_10,compute_10
```

Those are the default values. The compilation is performed by default to the virtual architecture `compute_10`, and the `a.out` that results from the compilation will include the CUBIN code for the `sm_10` real architecture, and the PTX assembly code for the `compute_10` architecture, which will be recompiled 'just in time' by the CUDA driver if your architecture is greater than `sm_10`.

Comment: The default architecture [now varies by CUDA version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932864/cuda-compute-capability-requirements), with newer releases.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the default is `compute_10`, as you cannot use any compute_13 features unless you specify explicitly that that's what you want. (Presumably the NVCC documentation that comes with the CUDA toolkit specifies, but I can't find a link online).

Comment: I guess you're right. I couldn't find that information when I took a look to the NVCC documentation. I'll look again, anyways.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that the default value for `-code` is the specified value in `-arch`, but I cannot find which is the default value for `-arch`.