# Which Compute Capability is supported by which CUDA versions?

Tags: cuda, version, cuda-driver, compute-capability

What are compute capabilities supported by each of:

1. CUDA 5.5?
2. CUDA 6.0?
3. CUDA 6.5?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30820513/what-is-the-correct-version-of-cuda-for-my-nvidia-driver/30820690#30820690

Answer (score 55, accepted):

| CUDA Version | Min CC | Deprecated CC | Default CC | Max CC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5.5 (and prior) | 1.0 | N/A | 1.0 | ? |
| 6.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | ? |
| 6.5 | 1.1 | 1.x | 2.0 | ? |
| 7.x | 2.0 | N/A | 2.0 | ? |
| 8.0 | 2.0 | 2.x | 2.0 | 6.2 |
| 9.x | 3.0 | N/A | 3.0 | 7.0 |
| 10.x | 3.0 | N/A <sup>*</sup> | 3.0 | 7.5 |
| 11.x | 3.5 <sup>†</sup> | 3.x | 5.2 | 11.0:8.0, 11.1:8.6, 11.8:9.0 |
| 12.x | 5.0 | N/A | 5.2 | 9.0 |

<sub>*  Compute Capability 3.0 was deprecated in 10.2.

†  CUDA 11.5 still "supports" cc3.5 devices; the R495 driver in CUDA 11.5 installer does not.</sub>

Column descriptions:

- **Min CC** = minimum compute capability that can be specified to nvcc (for that toolkit version)
- **Deprecated CC** = If you specify this CC, you will get a deprecation message, but compile should still proceed.
- **Default CC** = The architecture that will be targetted if no `-arch` or `-gencode` switches are used
- **Max CC** = The highest compute capability you can specify on the compile command line via arch switches (compute_XY, sm_XY)

Comment: Thanks! Actually I had some problems installing CUDA 6 on my GPU with CC 1.2 and thought that it's not supported. But it looks like the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Where did you find this information? Is there any official version, that is updated for CUDA 9.0?

Comment: Actually for CUDA 9.0: `GPU card with CUDA Compute Capability 3.0 or higher for building from source and 3.5 or higher for our binaries. ` as stated at https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.7/install/install_linux

Comment: @AndrzejPiasecki that is a requirement specific to Tensorflow (and it may change in the future), not a general CUDA requirement for use of CUDA 9.0.  This question is not about Tensorflow.

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler Tensorflow and CUDNN have a minimum cc of 3.0.  Not CUDA 8.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38542763/how-can-i-make-tensorflow-run-on-a-gpu-with-capability-2-0/38543201#38543201).

Comment: @RobertCrovella: I know you don't like edits of your answers, but I did take the liberty of reformatting as a proper table.

Comment: CUDA 11.8 still supports compiling for cc3.5 devices. Note that support of VS2022 appeared in CUDA 11.6.

Comment: Yes, that is why `3.5` appears in the `minCC` column in the 11.x row.