# CUDA Installation for NVidia Quadro FX 3800

Tags: cuda

I'm having trouble installing CUDA 7.0 (to use with TensorFlow) on a workstation with the Nvidia Quadro FX 3800.  I'm wondering if this is because the GPU is no longer supported.

Installation of the driver (340.96) seems to work fine:

```
$ sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.96.run

Installation of the NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64
(version: 340.96) is now complete. Please update your XF86Config or
xorg.conf file as appropriate; see the file
/usr/share/doc/NVIDIA_GLX-1.0/README.txt for details.
```

However, I think I may be having trouble with the following:

```
$ ./cuda_7.0.28_linux.run --kernel-source-path=/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-76-generic
The driver installation is unable to locate the kernel source. Please make sure
that the kernel source packages are installed and set up correctly. If you know
that the kernel source packages are installed and set up correctly, you may pass
the location of the kernel source with the '--kernel-source-path' flag.
...
Logfile is /tmp/cuda_install_1357.log

$ vi /tmp/cuda_install_1357.log
WARNING: The NVIDIA Quadro FX 3800 GPU installed in this system is
         supported through the NVIDIA 340.xx legacy Linux graphics drivers.
         Please visit http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html for more
         information.  The 346.46 NVIDIA Linux graphics driver will ignore
         this GPU.
WARNING: You do not appear to have an NVIDIA GPU supported by the 346.46
         NVIDIA Linux graphics driver installed in this system.  For
         further details, please see the appendix SUPPORTED NVIDIA GRAPHICS
         CHIPS in the README available on the Linux driver download page at
         www.nvidia.com.
...
ERROR: Unable to load the kernel module 'nvidia.ko'. This happens most
       frequently when this kernel module was built against the wrong or
       improperly configured kernel sources, with a version of gcc that
       differs from the one used to build the target kernel, or if a driver
       such as rivafb, nvidiafb, or nouveau is present and prevents the
       NVIDIA kernel module from obtaining ownership of the NVIDIA graphics
       device(s), or no NVIDIA GPU installed in this system is supported by
       this NVIDIA Linux graphics driver release.
...
Please see the log entries 'Kernel module load error' and 'Kernel
messages' at the end of the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for
more information.
```

Is the installation failure due to CUDA dropping support for this graphics card?

I followed the link trail: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus > https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-legacy-gpus > http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_quadro_fx_3800_us.html and I would have thought the Quadro FX 3800 supported CUDA (at least at the beginning).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the Quadro FX 3800 GPU is no longer supported by CUDA 7.0 and beyond.

The last CUDA version that supported that GPU was CUDA 6.5.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30820513/what-is-version-of-cuda-for-nvidia-304-125/30820690#30820690) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932864/cuda-compute-capability-requirements/28933055#28933055) may be of interest.  Your QFX 3800 is a [compute capability 1.3 device](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-legacy-gpus).

If you review the release notes that come with CUDA 7, you will find a notice of the elimination of support for these earlier GPUs.  Likewise, the newer CUDA driver versions also don't support those GPUs.