# Find supported GPU

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

I want to know if the latest CUDA version, which is 8.0, supports the GPUs in my computer, which are GeForce GTX 970 and Quadro K4200 (a dual-GPU system); I couldn't find the info online.

In general, how to find if a CUDA version, especially the newly released version, supports a specific Nvidia GPU?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In general, how to find if a CUDA version, especially the newly released version, supports a specific Nvidia GPU?

All CUDA versions from CUDA 7.0 to CUDA 8.0 support GPUs that have a compute capability of 2.0 or higher.  Both of your GPUs are in this category.

Prior to CUDA 7.0, some older GPUs were supported also.  You can find details of that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932864/cuda-compute-capability-requirements).

Note that CUDA 8.0 has announced that development for compute capability 2.0 and 2.1 is *deprecated*, meaning that support for these (Fermi) GPUs may be dropped in a future CUDA release.

In general, a list of currently supported CUDA GPUs and their compute capabilities is maintained by NVIDIA [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) although the list occasionally has omissions for very new GPUs just released.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt and thorough answer!

Comment: One more question: how to find the GPU driver version that a CUDA version requires?

Comment: For CUDA 8, just use the driver that comes with the CUDA toolkit installer.  For previous CUDA versions, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30820513/what-is-version-of-cuda-for-nvidia-304-125)

Comment: Thanks, but again, how do I know if the driver in the CUDA 8.0 toolkit installer supports my GPUs?

Comment: The driver in the cuda 8 toolkit supports every GPU that was available at the time of release I.e. about a week ago. So your GPUs are supported. More generally you can install the latest driver for your GPU and it will work with any previously released CUDA toolkit.