# Pytorch Hardware Requirement

Tags: deep-learning, gpu, pytorch

**What is the minimum Computation Capability required by the latest PyTorch version?**

I have Nvidia Geforce 820M with computation capability 2.1. How can I run PyTorch models on my GPU `(if it doesn't support naturally)`

Comment: This is a really interesting question, it is a bit off-topic though (hardware). GCP was not the answer you were looking for, but you know when needs must.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at [this page](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/), PyTorch (even the somewhat oldest versions) support CUDA upwards from version `7.5`. Whereas, looking at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932864/cuda-compute-capability-requirements), CUDA `7.5` requires minimum Compute Capability `2.0`. So, on paper, your machine should support some older version of PyTorch which allows CUDA `7.5` or preferably `8.0` (as of writing this answer, the latest version uses minimum CUDA `9.2`).

However, PyTorch also requires cuDNN. So, cuDNN `6.0` works for CUDA `7.5`. But cuDNN `6.0` requires Compute Capability of `3.0`. So, mostly, PyTorch won't work on your machine. (Thanks for pointing out the cuDNN part [Robert Crovella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695960/robert-crovella))

Comment: pytorch [depends on cudnn](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-check-if-torch-uses-cudnn/21933) which requires a GPU of cc3.0 or higher.