# identifier "__shfl_down" is undefined for cuda-7.5

Tags: gcc, cuda

While compiling a program on cuda 7.5 with gcc 4.8.4 on ubuntu 14.04 (pretty old config), I get this error

```
error: identifier "__shfl_down" is undefined
      detected during instantiation of "T gmx_shfl_down_sync(unsigned int, T, unsigned int, int) [with T=float]"
```

which point to

```
template <typename T>
static __forceinline__ __device__
T gmx_shfl_down_sync(const unsigned int activeMask,
                 const T            var,
                 unsigned int       offset,
                 int                width = warp_size)
{
#if GMX_CUDA_VERSION < 9000
    GMX_UNUSED_VALUE(activeMask);
    return __shfl_down(var, offset, width);
#else
    return __shfl_down_sync(activeMask, var, offset, width);
#endif
}
```

Is there any way to fix that? I see this issue for old cuda versions, but haven't seen a clear answer for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warp shuffle intrinsics are only defined (only supported on) compute capability (cc) 3.0 architectures and higher.

After CUDA 8.0, those were the only GPUs supported by `nvcc`, so even if you compile for default architecture (3.0) it will compile correctly.

However for [CUDA 8.0 and prior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932864/cuda-compute-capability-requirements/28933055#28933055), cc 2.x architectures were still supported by `nvcc` and were still the "default" architecture (what you would get if you didn't specify any architecture switches on the `nvcc` compile command line).

Therefore, on CUDA 8.0 and prior (warp shuffle was introduced in CUDA 6), if you either specify a cc 2.x architecture, or specify no architecture, you will see this error.

Since warp shuffle is not supported on cc 2.x architectures, the solution is to explicitly specify a suitable architecture on your `nvcc` compile command line with `-arch=sm_30` or similar.

Comment: I am using C2075 which is SM_20. So that mean, I have to revert to older source code either.

Comment: Correct.  You cannot use any warp shuffle code on that GPU.